# Is there a way to create extensible arrays in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a very simple exercise where i'm registering clients names (strings) and i'm using an array to do that so when i add a new one i will use another auxiliary array and then increase the length of the original or i will use System.arrayCopy, is there any other way, of increasing an array length gradually as you need to add elements to that array, that dosen't involve auxiliary arrays?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for this in Java:

1. Increase the size of an array manually as you are doing.
2. Use a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`.